# Drools with Netbeans 6.1

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, drools

I've downloaded and started to use Drools on a pilot project via it's "default" platform Eclipse. However, I would like to use it in Netbeans just the way plug-in works in Eclipse.

Any ideas/shot-cuts to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a lot of features in the eclipse plugin, but there is (as yet) no plugin for eclipse.

You can of course use drools with netbeans just fine - just means that the IDE features that are rule specific won't be available, but it will work, its Just Another Library then !

(I use drools with intelliJ IDEA and I just created a little syntax definition to give me basic highlighting etc... but no other features. If I want them, I jump into eclipse).